# Regarding invariant subspace of Real vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am learning linear alzebra form the book Linear Alzebra Done Right by Axler. At page 77 he gives explains why some operator(rotation in this case) does not have an   invariant subspace in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $. Later on, at page 91 he proves a theorem saying *Every operator on a finite dimensional, non zero, real vector space has an invariant subspace of dimension $1$ or $2$*.My question is; Does not the example at page 77 contradict this theorem? What am I missing?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$ is an invariant subspace for any linear map defined on it.

Comment: The issue is complex vs. real. The rotation operator does have an invariant subspace, the whole space.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. We were unable to find 1-dimensional invariat subspace but the theorem still holds good because rotation transformation is invariant in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $. The problem was: I just looked for 1 dimensional subspace and completely forgot about 2 dimensional subspace. Thanks Chirs and copper hat

Comment: I think I should vote to delete this post. What do you think?